# Given a finite abelian group $G$, if $d\mid |G|$, then $\exists H \leq G$ such that $|H| =d.$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

May I verify if my proof to the b/m claim is correct? Thank you.

1.) Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. I have verified that if $p \in \mathbb{P}$ and $p$ $|$ $|G|$, then $\exists g \in G: o(g) =p.$ Hence, prove that if $d$ $|$ $|G|$, then $\exists H \leq G$ such that $|H| =d.$

Proof:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Assume the claim is true for all abelian $G$ with $|G| < n$

Now, let $G$ be abelian such that $|G| = n$ and $d$ $|$ $|G|.$

If $d \in \mathbb{P}$, then $\exists g \in G: o(g) = d$ whence $|\left \langle {g}\right \rangle| = d.$

If $d\not\in\mathbb{P}$ , let $d = pq,$ for some $ p \in \mathbb{P}$ and some $q \in \mathbb{N}.$ Also, let $n = dm,$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}.$ Then $\exists g \in G: o(g) =p.$ Since $G$ is abelian, $\left \langle {g}\right \rangle \lhd G$ and $|G/\left \langle {g}\right \rangle| = n/p =qm < n.$ By Induction hypothesis, $\exists H/\left \langle {g}\right \rangle \leq G/\left \langle {g}\right \rangle$ such that $|H/\left \langle {g}\right \rangle|=q.$ Note that $H \leq G.$ It follows that $|H|=q|\left \langle {g}\right \rangle|=d.$

Comment: Correct, except you need to say “Let G be an ABELIAN finite group.” at the beginning of your proof

Answer (score 3):

Very well done!

I would simply make explicit what $\mathbb P$ denotes. It is clear to me, given the context, but it never hurts to define your notation when a symbol is used to denote different things, depending on context.

Comment: Nice to validate +1

Comment: ${+1}$ have you ever see this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/480749/8581)? ;-)